# How to rotate igraph network plot?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to rotate the R package based igraph network plot. In the igraph guidebook not enough explanation how to use R code

```
tk_rotate(tkp.id, degree = NULL, rad = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. To get the best answer possible I would recommend trying to present a reproducible example [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That way others can see what you have tried, copy and paste your code and recommend a solution. Also check out the example code at the bottom of R help documents as these can help demo the functions you are interested in.

Comment: I have supplied an answer to you question in the meantime, if this does not help, please try and be more specific per above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the R package `igraph` according to the documentation:

> the tk_rotate rotates the figure, its parameter can be given either in degrees or in radians.

Of particular note is the argument `tkp.id`. Make sure you assign the tkplot window to this value so you can reference it as the `tkp.id` in the function.

> `tkp.id` The id of the tkplot window to close/reshape/etc.

Here is a reproducible example that demonstrates it's use:

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
g <- make_ring(10)
x <- tkplot(g)
tk_rotate(x, degree = NULL, rad = NULL)
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks @Dean, in what format to give 'degree' and 'rad' values?

Comment: Either degrees or radians as a numeric value. I'd encourage you to try it yourself in R and see what works to ensure you get the result you are after.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarKoli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.