# Can I rotate a network graph made by igraph::graph?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to replicate a figure from a text book with the `igraph` package.  This code draws  the structure correctly:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph( c( "W","X", "Y","Z", "Y","W", "Z","W"), dir=FALSE)
plot(g, vertex.shape = "none")
```

but the entire graphic is rotated so it does not match the book.  The above plot has the X node up at 1:00 on the clock face.  I would like it so it is out at 9:00.  I [saw a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143311/how-to-rotate-igraph-network-plot) that showed that igraph::tkplot() can be rotated but I need a static plot. Is there a way to rotate an igraph network plot that is not rendered with tkplot(g)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  you just need to control the layout. The default layout is done with `layout_nicely`. To get that layout only rotated, just save the layout and multiply by a rotation matrix. You may need to play around a little with just how big a rotation to use.

```
LO = layout_nicely(g)
angle = 2*pi * 7.5/12
RotMat = matrix(c(cos(angle),sin(angle),-sin(angle), cos(angle)), ncol=2)
LO2 = LO %*% RotMat

plot(g, vertex.shape = "none", layout = LO2)
```

[image: Graph with rotated layout]